# zu sich nach Hause

Tags: phrase

Ich habe den folgenden Satz gelesen:

> Ralf lädt Katrin für den übernächsten Samstag zu sich nach Hause ein.

Was bedeutet „zu sich nach Hause“? Dass sie in sein Haus gehen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Ausdruck

> zu sich nach Hause

bedeutet nur: *dahin, wo er oder sie wohnt*.

Im Falle von Ralf kann das sein eigenes Haus sein, wenn er dort auch wohnt. Es kann aber auch bloß eine Eigentums- oder Mietwohnung innerhalb eines Hauses sein. Strenggenommen könnte es sich sogar um eine auf Dauer angelegte Unterkunft handeln, zum Beispiel in einem Heim, einer Seniorenresidenz, einem Gefängnis oder wo auch immer.

Comment: Ich schließe daraus, dass es auf English "to his home" bedeutet. Gibt es eine einfachere Weise, das zu sagen(eg nach sein(e) Hause) ?

Answer (score 0):

Das sind einfach zwei adverbiale Bestimmungen des Ortes.

> Ralf lädt Katrin für den übernächsten Samstag zu sich ein.

Hier ist nicht ganz klar, wohin konkret Ralf Katrin einlädt, nur dass der Platz zu Ralf gehört. Ralfs Yacht?

> Ralf lädt Katrin für den übernächsten Samstag nach Hause ein.

Hier ist nicht ganz klar, um welches Haus es sich handelt. Ralfs? Das seiner Eltern?

Comment: Ist der erste Satz für sich genommen vollständig?  Ich kann die genaue Bedeutung von "zu sich" nicht ableiten und Google Translate auch nicht.

Comment: *Zu sich* weist darauf hin, dass es sich um Ralfs Zuhause handelt.

Comment: I am a little confused with German terms here, so I'll switch to English. So, "zu sich" means his home and "zu sich nach Hause" means the same. However, the latter is more specific and makes clear that his home is a house (and not a boat, for instance). Is that right?

Comment: *zu sich* means *to his place*, and it's not clear what kind of place that might be. His home, his yacht etc.

Comment: *zu sich* could also be interpreted as "to his current location"